# Standalone installer for F# fsi

Tags: f#

I just wanted to know if there is or will be a standalone installer for fsi.exe to run on machines (Windows) that are not connected to the internet?

I have managed to get fsi working by downloading the nuget package, unzipping and then manually adding the "tools" folder to the PATH environment variable.

This seems to work because I can get into the repl, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

This is a client server that we access over a tightly controlled VPN and it is not an option to do a full Visual Studio installation.

Comment: I builded a script myself to ship with solution and [this](https://i.imgur.com/1BCMuWe.png) package was enough to work with `fsx` files

Comment: Thanks - that would make it easier

Comment: You should ship all script dependencies separately. Image above shows dlls only to start `fsi.exe`

Comment: Cool, mostly using the dotnet assemblies which I can reference from the fsx file without any extra setup